# Function error: "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'"

Tags: swift, function

I am currently working on a school assignment for my coding class. In this assignment, we are creating a function that takes a number grade (a Double) and divides it by the numberOfHours to get a GPA variable. I have run into an error though in my code:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'

I do not understand this error and I am trying to fix the code by changing what's an Int and what's a Double, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The code where the error is coming from is:

```
// create your function here
func gpaUpdater(moreHours hours: Double, moreGPA grade: Double) -> Int {
    let addedHours: Int = hours + attemptedHours
    let calculatedGPA: Double = hours / grade
    //gpa = gpa + grade
    print(calculatedGPA)
    return calculatedGPA
}
```

Full code below:

```swift
//  My Functions Playground.swift
//
//
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

/*
 We're going to track your GPA from one semester to the next. Assume at the end of your sophomore years, you have attempted 60 hours and have earned 222.5 grade points. Assign attempted hours and grade points to variables. Write a function that updates your current GPA and assigns it to the GPA var (you'll update it along the way). Label your function arguments. Print your new GPA from within the function.

 At the end of the current semester, add 16 hours and 60 grade points to your record. Call the gpa function to update your overall gpa.

 Test your gpa at the end of the year to see if any administrative action needs to be taken. If the gpa is less than 1.8, the student will need to be placed on suspension. If less than 2.0, we need to put the student on probation. If over 3.5, we'll put the student on the dean's list, and if over 3.9, we'll put the student on the president's list. Create a switch that prints the recommended adminstrative action. If no action is required, print, "Carry on. Nothing to see here." Create internal and external labels for your arguments.

 */

var gpa: Double
var attemptedHours: Int
var earnedGradePoints: Int

// create your function here
func gpaUpdater(moreHours hours: Double, moreGPA grade: Double) -> Int {
    let addedHours: Int = hours + attemptedHours
    let calculatedGPA: Double = hours / grade
    //gpa = gpa + grade
    print(calculatedGPA)
    return calculatedGPA
}

// call the function
gpaUpdater(moreHours: 16, moreGPA: 60)

// add the new hours and grade points here and call the function again
func switchFunction() {
    switch gpa {
    case gpa..<1.8:
        print("You will be placed on suspension")
    case 1.8...2.0:
        print("You will be placed on probation")
    case 3.5...3.8:
        print("You will be put on the dean's list.")
    case 3.9..<gpa:
        print("You will be put on the president's list.")
    default:
        print("Carry on. Nothing to see here.")
    }
}
switchFunction()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
let addedHours: Int = hours + attemptedHours
```

to

```
let addedHours =  Int(hours) + attemptedHours
```

Comment: Better yet, `let addedHours =  Int(hours) + attemptedHours`. Even better would be to keep the `Double` result to avoid loss of precision.

Comment: yes......I confused what was the Double , I agree but this will handle the error at first , then he should know the best for his case

Comment: I think you missed my primary point. You don't need the `: Int`.

Comment: Thank You for your help so far. I'm now getting a return error though related to the function that states: "28:12: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Double' to return type 'Int'." Putting Int(x) in front of the return statement doesn't fix that.

Comment: function name ????

Comment: It's because of the same problem. You're returning a Double when your function gpaUpdater says that it should return an Int.

Comment: Okay I fixed it. No value is being put into the gpaUpdater function, but at least I have no errors. That's another problem for another post. Thank you!